# Proving that $\int_a^bf^pd\alpha=0$ implies $\int_a^bfd\alpha=0$ for $f \in \mathcal{R}(\alpha)$ and $f\ge0$ on $[a,b]$

Tags: real-analysis

The question posed may seem trivial to many. But I couldn't find a trivial solution to above within the theory upto Riemann-Stieltjes integral. I woudn't be considering arguments from Lebesgue theory as I haven't studied it so far. Here I would try to prove it from within the theory of Riemann-Stieltjes integral.
No assumption is made regarding continuity of $f$.

$\alpha$ is monotonically increasing on $[a,b]$

Let $A=\alpha(b)-\alpha(a)$

Let $M=sup\{f(x)|x \in [a,b]\}$

$f \in \mathcal{R}(\alpha)$ on $[a,b]$

$f \ge 0$ on $[a,b]$

Given $\int_a^bf^pd\alpha=0$

For any $\epsilon > 0$ there exists a partition $P$ of $[a,b]$, $P=\{a=x_0<x_1...<x_i<...<x_n=b\}$ such that $U(P,f^p,\alpha)=\sum_1^nM_i(\alpha(x_i)-\alpha(x_{i-1}))< \epsilon$ where $M_i=sup\{(f(x))^p|x \in [x_i,x_{i-1}]\}$. For any $k>0$ let $K=\{i|M_i>k^p\}$. Let $l(K)=\sum_{i \in K}(\alpha(x_i)-\alpha(x_{i-1}))$.

Now $$k^p.l(K)<\epsilon \implies l(K)<\frac{\epsilon}{k^p}$$
Choosing $\epsilon< k^p\delta \implies l(K)<\delta$ for any $\delta > 0$

For the same partition $P, K'=\{i|M'_i>k\}=K$ where $M'_i=sup\{f(x)|x \in [x_i,x_{i-1}]\}$

$U(P,f,\alpha)\le M.l(K)+k.A<M\delta+kA$.

Both $\delta$ and $k$ can be chosen to be arbitrarily small. Hence $U(P,f,\alpha)$ can be made to be as close to $0$ as we wish.

This proves $\int_a^bfd\alpha=0$

Any trivial proof would be welcome.

Comment: Will using Hölder's inequality (http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/286473/proving-h%C3%B6lders-inequality) be considered as cheating?

Comment: @rtybase yes. I needed above result to prove the holder's inequality in the trivial case

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Take a step function $0\le s\le f$. Then $0\le s^p\le f^p$ and so $0\le \int s^p dx\le\int f^pdx=0$. Hence $\int s^pdx=0$ but since s is piecewise constant, this implies that $s=0$. In particular, $\int s dx=0$ and since this is true for every step function below $f$ then the lower Riemann integral of $f$ must be zero.

Comment: Looks correct, but can it be shown that such a step function can always be chosen, as we are not assuming anything abt continuity of $f$

Comment: Well,it depends on the definition of lower Riemann integral that you use. If you take it to be $\sup\{\sum_i (t_i-t_{i-1})\inf_{[t_{i-1},t_i)}f \}$, where the supremum is taken over all partitions of $[0,1]$ then each function $s$ which takes value  $\inf_{[t_{i-1},t_i)}f $ in $[t_{i-1},t_i)$ is a step function

Answer (score 0):

I believe, some constraints must be imposed on $p$, at least it must not be $0$. But, for a large class of values of $p$, specifically $p>1$, [Hölder's inequality](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/286473/proving-h%C3%B6lders-inequality) can be used. E.g.

$$0\leq \int_{a}^{b}fd\alpha = \int_{a}^{b}f\cdot 1d\alpha \leq \left(\int_{a}^{b}f^pd\alpha \right)^{\frac{1}{p}}\cdot \left(\int_{a}^{b}1^qd\alpha \right)^{\frac{1}{q}}=0$$

Comment: Actually I needed to prove the above (theorem) to prove holder's inequality in the trivial case i.e, if $\int_{a}^{b}f\cdot gd\alpha \leq \left(\int_{a}^{b}f^pd\alpha \right)^{\frac{1}{p}}\cdot \left(\int_{a}^{b}g^qd\alpha \right)^{\frac{1}{q}}=0$ when either $\left(\int_{a}^{b}f^pd\alpha \right)^{\frac{1}{p}}$ or $\left(\int_{a}^{b}g^qd\alpha \right)^{\frac{1}{q}}$ is zero.

Comment: Well, we can try Hölder's inequality for the sums and consider that the limits preserve the order too, e.g.:

$$\sum_{i=1}^{n} f_i\cdot g_i \leq   \left ( \sum_{i=1}^{n}  f_i^p  \right )^{\frac{1}{p}} \cdot \left ( \sum_{i=1}^{n} g_i^q \right )^{\frac{1}{q}}$$
And $h=h^{\frac{1}{p}}\cdot h^{\frac{1}{q}}$, assuming an equidistant partition, leading to

$$\sum_{i=1}^{n} f_i\cdot g_i\cdot h \leq \left ( \sum_{i=1}^{n}  f_i^p \cdot h \right )^{\frac{1}{p}} \cdot \left ( \sum_{i=1}^{n} g_i^q \cdot h \right )^{\frac{1}{q}}$$

Answer (score 0):

You do not need p>1. My previous answer works. If you don't like step functions, take a partition $a=t_0<\cdots<t_n=b$ and consider $\inf_{[t_{i-1},t_i]}f$. Then $$0\le \sum_i(\alpha(t_i)-\alpha(t_{i-1}))\inf_{[t_{i-1},t_i]}f^p\le \int_a^b f^pd\alpha=0$$ and so $(\alpha(t_i)-\alpha(t_{i-1}))\inf_{[t_{i-1},t_i]}f^p=0$ for every $i$, which implies that $\alpha(t_i)-\alpha(t_{i-1})=0$ or $\inf_{[t_{i-1},t_i]}f^p=0$. If $\inf_{[t_{i-1},t_i]}f^p=0$, then $\inf_{[t_{i-1},t_i]}f=0$ (just play with the definition of inf). So you have $\sum_i(\alpha(t_i)-\alpha(t_{i-1}))\inf_{[t_{i-1},t_i]}f=0$ for every lower sum and thus $\int_a^b f d\alpha=0$. This is really the same idea behind the other proof.