# David Williams "Probability with Martingales" 6.13.a : proof of Holder inequality using Jensen

Tags: probability-theory, measure-theory, proof-explanation

I am aware of this answer : [Hölder inequality from Jensen inequality](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/211633/h%C3%B6lder-inequality-from-jensen-inequality) but still I am unsure about the last statement in this proof of the Holder inequality (also using the Jensen inequality) in the above book:

[image]

I understand that the highlighted green section is because $c(x)=x^q, q>1$ is convex and from Jensen: $c(E(X))={E(X)}^q\le E(c(X))=E(X^q)$ with $E(X)=P(X)=\int_{\Omega}XdP$ but I am still struggling with the last highlighted statement ...

Answer (score 0):

In case it helps someone, I have found a clearer (for me) proof in Jacod's "Probability Essentials" :

[image]

Answer (score 0):

From the definition of $u$ and $\Bbb P$ it follows that $\mu(fh)=\Bbb P(u)\cdot\mu(f^p)$. As you note, Jensen implies that $\Bbb P(u)\le [\Bbb P(u^q)]^{1/q}$. Finally, 
$$
\Bbb P(u^q)=\mu(h^q/[f^{p-1}]^q\cdot 1_{\{f>0\}}\cdot f^p)/\mu(f^p)=\mu(h^q1_{\{f>0\}})/\mu(f^p),
$$
so
$$
[\Bbb P(u^q)]^{1/q}\cdot\mu(f^p)=\|h1_{\{f>0\}}\|_{L^q(\mu)}\cdot\mu(f^p)^{1-1/q}=\|h1_{\{f>0\}}\|_{L^q(\mu)}\cdot\|f\|_{L^p(\mu)}.
$$