# Proof of Holder's Inequality using Jensen's Inequality - Integrability

Tags: probability-theory, measure-theory, inequality, holder-inequality, jensen-inequality

I did not find any posts regarding this: So I was reading the [Alternate proof of Holder's inequality](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/H%C3%B6lder%27s_inequality#Proof_of_H.C3.B6lder.27s_inequality). What I am confused is the this bolden part:

> From Jensen's inequality,
> $$ \int h \, d \nu = \Big( \int h^p \, d\nu\Big)^{\frac{1}{p}}$$
> where $\nu$ is a probability measure, and $h$ is **any $\nu$-measurable function**.

The proof I know of requires $h$ to be integrable, or at least $\int h \,d \nu < \infty$.

---

Supposing this condition is required. If we proceed the proof, we need to *first show*
$$ \int hg \, d\nu < \infty$$
without invoking the inequality. But this seems to be what we are proving.

---

I believe I am interpreting something wrong. What am I missing?

Comment: There is an easy proof of Holder for two sequences by Jensen for $f(x)=x^k$, where $k\geq1.$ See also here: https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/211633/

Comment: Ok, so this is exactly the same proof? So my problem would be why is $h$ integrable - or: what is the proof of the first part without $f$ being integrable?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Hölder inequality from Jensen inequality](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/211633/h%c3%b6lder-inequality-from-jensen-inequality)

Comment: It might have been simpler to ask about the case when $\int h \;\mathrm d \nu$ is infinite.  Certainly we can give a probability measure $\nu$ and a $\nu$-measurable function $h$ for which the "expectation" is infinite.  The status of the "inequality" is then clear.  Note also that while asking about an inequality, the body of the Question currents contains an *equality*.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think what's missing is that when $h$ is non-negative, if
$\int h \,d\nu=\infty$, then $\int h^p\,d\nu=\infty$, so that Jensen's inequality applies to any $\nu$-measurable function.

*Proof:*

Let $A=h^{-1}([0,1))$. Let $B=A^C$. These are measurable since $h$ is. Then by assumption, 
$$\infty = \int h \,d\nu = \int_A h\,d\nu + \int_B h\, d\nu,$$
 and $\int_Ah\,d\nu \le 1$ (since $h\le 1$ on $A$, and $\nu$ is a probability measure), so we must have $\int_Bh\,d\nu=\infty$. Then on $B$, $h\le h^p$, so $\int_Bh^P\,d\nu = \infty$, and then $\int h^p\,d\nu \ge \int_B h^p\,d\nu$. Hence $\int h^p\,d\nu=\infty$ as well.

Comment: Thanks, agreed. This is also what I typed under Rigel's answer. :P

Comment: Yeah I saw that afterwards. This was also what threw me for a loop when I first read your question, so I figured that this was what you were asking about.

Answer (score 2):

Jensen's inequality, in this case, states that
$$
\int h d\nu \leq \left(\int h^p d\nu\right)^{1/p}
$$
provided that $\nu$ is a probability measure and $h$ is a non-negative $\nu$-measurable function.
(There is no loss of generality assuming that $h\geq 0$, since we can replace a complex-valued $h$ with its module $|h|$.)

Clearly, both. sides of this inequality can be $+\infty$.

You do not need to first show that $\int fg d\nu$ is finite. Here $f$ and $g$ are again non-negative $\nu$-measurable functions, and that integral can be $+\infty$.

Comment: My problem is why the Jensen inequality states the line. Yes, clearly then can both be $\infty$, but what you need to show is $\int h \,d\nu = \infty \Rightarrow \int h^p \, d\nu = \infty$, i.e. the inequality is true? 

I think this explains: if $\int h \,d \nu < \infty$, we apply the usual Jensen inequality. If $\int h \, d\nu = \infty$, then inequality holds as otherwise, $\int h^p \,d \nu \Rightarrow \int h \, d\nu < \infty$ from monoticity of norms.

Comment: For probability measures, the map $p \mapsto \|f\|_p$ is increasing.

Comment: Yes, thanks for the clarification.