# Proving an inequality related to ratio of norms to measures

Tags: real-analysis, probability, probability-theory, measure-theory, lp-spaces

> Let $\mu$ be a finite measure on a measurable space $(X, \mathcal{F})$
>   and let $1 \leq r < s < +\infty$. Prove that for every $f \in
>  L^{s}(X)$, it holds that
>
> $$\frac{||f||_{L^{r}(X)}}{\mu (X)^{1/r}} \leq
>  \frac{||f||_{L^{s}(\Omega)}}{\mu (X)^{1/s}} $$

I am studying for an exam, and this is a previous year's problem. I really have no clue how to approach this problem since I am quite new to $L^{p}$ spaces. I've been working with the definitions, and many of the theorems are confusing to me. I would greatly appreciate any help in approaching this problem. By the way, this is a question from a probability exam so $\Omega$ denotes a sample space.

Comment: The title and the question appear disjoint.

Comment: Thanks for catching that.

Comment: First [prove the claim for a probability space](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/211633/8157) ($\mu(X)=1$). Then it will be clear that what you have is not really a generalization.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is just Holder's in equality: $\int  |f |^{r} d\mu =\int (1)  (|f |^{r}) d\mu \leq (\int 1^{p} d\mu)^{1/p} (\int |f|^{rq}d\mu)^{1/q}$ where $q=\frac  s r$ and $p =\frac q {q-1}$.

This gives $\|f\|_r \leq  (\mu(X))^{\frac 1 {pr}}) (\|f_s||)$ since $qr=s$.  Now $\frac 1 {pr} =\frac  {s-r} {sr}=\frac 1 r-\frac  1 s$. Divide both sides by $(\mu(X))^{1/r}$ to finish the proof.

Comment: I'm having trouble seeing the conclusion from here. I see that the left-hand side gives $||f_{L^{r}(X)}||$, and the first term on the right-hand side of the inequality gives $||1||_{p}$. How does the second term come into play? Also, don't we require $p + q = 1$? Finally, how do we get the measures $\mu(X)^{1/r}$ and $\mu(X)^{1/s}$ in there?

Comment: @hom I have added some details. Note that $p=\frac q {q-1}$ is equivalent to $\frac  1 p +\frac 1 q=1$ so Holder's inequality can be applied.

Comment: Did you mean to write $(\int 1^{p r} \mathop{d\mu})^{1/pr}$? (it's still the same thing -- just wondering)

Comment: @hom I am writing $|f|^{r}$ as the product of $1$ and $|f|^{r}$ so what I have written is correct.